# chrome extension: chrome.commands shortcut affecting incognito window, even though extension isn't enabled there

Tags: google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

Chrome extension development: I am using the chrome.commands to specify certain global shortcuts.

If I specify a shortcut that overrides a default browser shortcut (for which I have a good reason!), things work fine mostly, i.e. my extension's action gets invoked instead of the browser's default.

However in an incognito window, invoking this shortcut neither invokes my extension's action (which is okay since the extension is disabled there by default), nor the browser's overridden action. (If I allow the extension in incognito mode, my shortcut works fine again as expected.)

Before I file a bug for this, I wanted to check if there's a way to fix this myself.

Related: Using chrome.commands is there a way to make keyboard event not prevent the default action, as one happens by default with regular DOM events?